# Pull out records from 3 tables in Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have got 3 tables in my database. Company, Product and Lead. Below are my fields.

### Leads Table:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[BuySellTypeId]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[Keywords]
      ,[CategoryId] // categoryid
      ,[SubCategoryId]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ProductImagePath]
      ,[CreationDate]
      ,[ExpiryDate]
      ,[CompanyId] // company id
      ,[ShortDescription]
      ,[IsExpired]
      ,[IsActive]
  FROM [BuySell]
```

### Products Table:

```
SELECT   
        Id, 
        Name, 
        Description, 
        ImagePath, 
        CompanyId, //company id
        Keywords, 
        CategoryId,  // categoryid
        SubCategoryId, 
        PostedDate, 
        ExpiryDate, 
        ShortDescription, 
        IsActive,                       
        IsExpired
FROM  Products
```

I have one more table "**Company**" whose reference is shown above in the two tables. My requirement is to pull out all companies that exists in above tables, Products and BuySell in same categories.
For example If I want to see all companies of CategoryId = 15, then it will pull all companies with categoryid= 15 from buysell and products table. Obviously there will be redundancy, so i will use `Distinct()` to extract distinct items.

My Linq2Sql Biz layer method

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all companies by category id that exists in Lead and Products
        ///table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="categoryId">category id as integer</param>
        /// <param name="take">records to take</param>
        /// <param name="skip">records to skip</param>
        /// <returns>List of companies</returns>
        public static IList GetCompaniesByCategory(int categoryId, int take, int skip)
        {
            return (from c in Context.Companies
                   join bs in Context.BuySells on c.CompanyId equals bs.CompanyId
                   join p in Context.Products on c.CompanyId equals p.CompanyId
                   where bs.CategoryId == categoryId || p.CategoryId==categoryId
                   select new
                              {
                                  c.CompanyId,
                                  c.CompanyName,
                                  c.Country.Flag,
                                  c.Profile,
                                  c.IsUsingSMSNotifications,
                                  c.IsVerified,
                                  c.MembershipType,
                                  c.RegistrationDate, c.ShortProfile,
                              }).Skip(skip).Take(take).Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

But the above code return me 0 items. When i design its sql , see below,

```
SELECT     dbo.Company.CompanyId, dbo.Company.CompanyName, dbo.Company.Name, dbo.Company.IsVerified, dbo.Company.IsUsingSMSNotifications, 
                      dbo.Company.CompanyLogo, dbo.Company.RegistrationDate, dbo.Company.Profile
FROM         dbo.BuySell INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Company ON dbo.BuySell.CompanyId = dbo.Company.CompanyId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Products ON dbo.Company.CompanyId = dbo.Products.CompanyId
WHERE     (dbo.BuySell.CategoryId = 1) AND (dbo.Products.CategoryId = 1)
```

i am able to get the company from BuySell but not from Product. So please help me. `I need the LINQ equivalent statement. To replace the above cs code.`

Comment: I don't think this SQL is the one generated from that query. Do you have any relation between the company table and buysells and products tables?

Comment: 1. Sql is designed in Management Studio, not Linq generated. 2. Yes , they do have relations, see the tables and commented lines above....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any relation between those tables, the query might be much simpler

```
return (from c in Context.Companies
where c.BuySells.Any( b=>b.CategoryId == categoryId)
      || c.Products.Any( p=>p.CategoryId == categoryId)
select new
{
  c.CompanyId,
  c.CompanyName,
  c.Country.Flag,
  c.Profile,
  c.IsUsingSMSNotifications,
  c.IsVerified,
  c.MembershipType,
  c.RegistrationDate, c.ShortProfile,
}).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

*The query used with SSMS checks for CategoryId = 1 and uses an AND condition, but your LINQ query uses an OR condition*

Comment: One thing "The LINQ query uses an OR condition", what do you mean by that, I can see you have used && in where condition. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, your LINQ query uses that

Comment: So you want to say I have to use && instead of ||. One more time , i would like to clear, i need the company from either or both the tables. If it only exists in prodcuts then also, and if it only exists in leads then also and if exists in both products abd leads then from both table. So in that case && is appropriate or || will be applied